# Assign stores by areas using OpenStreetMap

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

A company has stores (lat/lng) located throughout the country, these are displayed using OSM. So far so good.

Now they have the requirement to assign areas/borders to their stores to define responsibilities. You can compare responsibility areas with those of post office (responsibility areas are determined and allocated by hand, it's not shortest distance). So if a customer is searching for a store (geolocation) the responsible/prefered one should get a special icon.

Is there a (gis) standard available to define/store areas/borders? Does OSM offer special functions to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSM doesn't offer anything for such tasks because OSM is mainly a database. But there are lots of applications and frameworks around OSM which can be very helpful.

Your question sounds like you want to visualize isochrones which is incidentally very similar to a [question recently asked on gis.stackexchange.com about drawing isochrones on an OSM map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118533/drawing-isochrones-on-map). Does the solution(s) suggested for this question help you?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need shortest distance. I updated my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Isn't that even simpler? If you already have the pre-defined responsibility areas then all you need is a spatial query on your database in order to determine in which responsibility area a given coordinate is located.

Comment: Thank you very much! Spatial (query) was the missing keyword. Now I know how I can solve it.